# Apache Reverse Proxy SSL don't carrying cookies

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, cookies

We have an Apache 2.4 reverse proxy setup on a Windows server. The server should redirect users to other server via reverse proxy and store the cookies.
We set it up, it works fine except that no cookies are set on the client.

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  SSLEngine on
  ServerName localhost:443
  SSLCertificateFile "C:/Cert/targetdomain.com/fullchain1.pem"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/Cert/targetdomain.com/privkey1.pem"
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ 
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain "https://targetdomain.com" "http://localhost:8080"
  ProxyPassReverseCookiePath  "/"  "/"
</Virtualhost>
```

Can someone help me?